# Angular AOT build error - Maximum call stack size exceeded, resolving symbol XXX in Path

Tags: angular, npm

I have create an Angular library contains the services in my project
and I have imported the library inside the project and test it without any problems.

But when I am trying to make an AOT build for my angular project 
this error appear

```
Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded, resolving symbol SimpleAuthService in C:/i.rabeea/workspaces/hero/fulfillment_angular/node_modules/zwp-modules/auth/index.d.ts, resolving symbol SimpleAuthService in C:/i.rabeea/workspaces/hero/fulfillment_angular/node_modules/zwp-modules/auth/index.d.ts, ...
at syntaxError (C:\i.rabeea\workspaces\hero\fulfillment_angular\node_modules\@angular\compiler\@angular\compiler.es5.js:1699:2)
at simplifyInContext (C:\i.rabeea\workspaces\hero\fulfillment_angular\node_modules\@angular\compiler\@angular\compiler.es5.js:24949:17)
at StaticReflector.simplify (C:\i.rabeea\workspaces\hero\fulfillment_angular\node_modules\@angular\compiler\@angular\compiler.es5.js:24961:7)
at StaticReflector.annotations (C:\i.rabeea\workspaces\hero\fulfillment_angular\node_modules\@angular\compiler\@angular\compiler.es5.js:24388:38)
at NgModuleResolver.resolve (C:\i.rabeea\workspaces\hero\fulfillment_angular\node_modules\@angular\compiler\@angular\compiler.es5.js:14720:34)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (C:\i.rabeea\workspaces\hero\fulfillment_angular\node_modules\@angular\compiler\@angular\compiler.es5.js:15372:58)
at addNgModule (C:\i.rabeea\workspaces\hero\fulfillment_angular\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24268:58)
at C:\i.rabeea\workspaces\hero\fulfillment_angular\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24279:14
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at _createNgModules (C:\i.rabeea\workspaces\hero\fulfillment_angular\node_modules\@angular\compiler\@angular\compiler.es5.js:24248:8)
at analyzeNgModules (C:\i.rabeea\workspaces\hero\fulfillment_angular\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24153:14)
at analyzeAndValidateNgModules (C:\i.rabeea\workspaces\hero\fulfillment_angular\node_modules\@angular\compiler\@angular\compiler.es5.js:24133:19)
at AotCompiler.analyzeModulesAsync (C:\i.rabeea\workspaces\hero\fulfillment_angular\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23797:46)
at CodeGenerator.codegen (C:\i.rabeea\workspaces\hero\fulfillment_angular\packages\compiler-cli\src\codegen.ts:41:10)
at C:\i.rabeea\workspaces\hero\fulfillment_angular\node_modules\src\main.ts:19:84
at Object.main (C:\i.rabeea\workspaces\hero\fulfillment_angular\node_modules\@angular\tools\@angular\tsc-wrapped\src\main.ts:136:12)
at Object.runInternal (C:\i.rabeea\workspaces\hero\fulfillment_angular\node_modules\src\main.ts:24:10)
at C:\i.rabeea\workspaces\hero\fulfillment_angular\node_modules\src\plugin.ts:64:21
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:667:11)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:607:3
```

And this is the script that make the problem 
"build:aot:prod:base"

When I remove this token "cross-env BUILD_AOT=1" from script it work will, but I need this when run the app in prodution.

```
"scripts": {
"build:aot:prod:base": "npm run clean:dist && npm run clean:aot && cross-env BUILD_AOT=1 npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile --bail",
"build:aot:dev-conf": "cross-env CONF_FILE=./config.dev.json npm run build:aot:prod:base",
"build:aot:prod-conf": "cross-env CONF_FILE=./config.prod.json npm run build:aot:prod:base",
"build:aot:prod": "cross-env CONF_FILE=./config.dev.json npm run build:aot:prod:base",
"build:aot": "npm run build:aot:prod",
"build:dev": "npm run clean:dist && npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile",
"build:docker": "npm run build:prod && docker build -t angular2-webpack-start:latest .",
"build:prod": "npm run clean:dist && npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile --bail",
"build": "npm run build:dev",
"ci:aot": "npm run lint && npm run test && npm run build:aot && npm run e2e",
"ci:jit": "npm run lint && npm run test && npm run build:prod && npm run e2e",
"ci:nobuild": "npm run lint && npm test && npm run e2e",
"ci:testall": "npm run lint && npm run test && npm run build:prod && npm run e2e && npm run build:aot && npm run e2e",
"ci:travis": "npm run lint && npm run test && npm run build:aot && npm run e2e:travis",
"ci": "npm run ci:testall",
"clean:all": "npm run rimraf -- doc coverage dist compiled dll",
"clean:dll": "npm run rimraf -- dll",
"clean:aot": "npm run rimraf -- compiled",
"clean:dist": "npm run rimraf -- dist",
"clean:install": "npm set progress=false && npm install",
"clean": "npm cache clean --force && npm run rimraf -- node_modules doc coverage dist compiled dll",
"deploy:prod": "npm run clean:all && npm prune --force && npm install && npm version patch",
"deploy:test": "npm run clean:all && npm prune --force && npm install && npm test && npm run build:aot:prod",
"docker": "docker",
"docs": "npm run typedoc -- --options typedoc.json --exclude '**/*.spec.ts' ./src/",
"docs:compodoc": "compodoc -p tsconfig.json",
"docs:compodoc:serve": "compodoc -p tsconfig.json -s",
"docs:compodoc:serve:watch": "compodoc -p tsconfig.json -s -w",
"e2e:live": "npm-run-all -p -r server:prod:ci protractor:live",
"e2e:travis": "npm-run-all -p -r server:prod:ci protractor:delay",
"e2e": "npm-run-all -p -r server:prod:ci protractor",
"github-deploy:dev": "npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack.github-deploy.js --progress --profile --env.githubDev",
"github-deploy:prod": "npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack.github-deploy.js --progress --profile --env.githubProd",
"github-deploy": "npm run github-deploy:dev",
"lint": "npm run tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
"node": "node",
"postinstall": "npm run webdriver:update",
"postversion": "git push && git push --tags",
"preclean:install": "npm run clean",
"preversion": "npm test",
"protractor": "protractor",
"protractor:delay": "sleep 3 && npm run protractor",
"protractor:live": "protractor --elementExplorer",
"rimraf": "rimraf",
"server:dev:hmr": "npm run server:dev -- --hotOnly",
"server:dev:hmr:browser": "npm run server:dev:browser -- --hotOnly",
"server:dev": "npm run rimraf -- .awcache && npm run webpack-dev-server -- --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/",
"server:dev:browser": "npm run server:dev -- --open",
"server:prod": "http-server dist -c-1 --cors",
"server:prod:ci": "http-server dist -p 3001 -c-1 --cors",
"server": "npm run server:dev",
"start:hmr": "npm run server:dev:hmr",
"start:hmr:browser": "npm run server:dev:hmr:browser",
"start": "npm run server:dev",
"test": "npm run lint && karma start",
"tslint": "tslint",
"typedoc": "typedoc",
"version": "npm run build:aot:prod",
"watch:dev:hmr": "npm run watch:dev -- --hot",
"watch:dev": "npm run build:dev -- --watch",
"watch:prod": "npm run build:prod -- --watch",
"watch:aot:prod": "npm run build:aot:prod -- --watch",
"watch:test": "npm run test -- --auto-watch --no-single-run",
"watch": "npm run watch:dev",
"webdriver-manager": "webdriver-manager",
"webdriver:start": "npm run webdriver-manager start",
"webdriver:update": "webdriver-manager update",
"webpack-dev-server": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
"webpack": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js"
}
```

Comment: You probably have a circular dependency in your code. See this related [GitHub Ticket #6309](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6309)

Comment: you may try --force tag also.

Comment: @BlackEagle, I have used --force tag with no success.

Comment: @Igor, thank you for the link, I will check the module if there any circular dependency in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would search your code for references to SimpleAuthService.

Credit to Igor regarding the circular dependency concern e.g. be careful how barrels are used e.g. fileA imports SimpleAuthService which also imports an index.ts which imports SimpleAuthService or such other circular relations. In such a scenario, one approach could be to explicity import certain items instead of via a barrel.

Note: you will generally catch more compilation issues during AOT and that is a good thing! i.e. its good practice to run with AOT compilation during your dev cycle now and then to ensure it's ready for PROD build. AOT catches legitimate problems.

Comment: I have figured it out, this error appear because of fileA import SimpleAuthService from main index.ts file, I just make fileA import it from its original path, I don't why barrel file not work.

Comment: Cool. AuthServices tend to be imported in multiple locations easily leading to circular relationships when combined with barrels. Sounds like you broke the circular relationship.